# Hibernate 5 do not have FieldHandled class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I was updating the hibernate 3.x to 5.x. In order to handle the lasyloading problems we have used classes with `FieldHandled`. But it looks like Hibernate 5 do not have it any more. Any idea what should I be using now ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is `FieldHandled` interface in Hibernate 5. I'm using it successfully:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/bytecode/internal/javassist/FieldHandled.html

Comment: Not totally correct, While `FieldHandled` is effectively present in hibernate 5.0 it is not in 5.10 [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/).